# Deploy Django project on ubuntu

Tags: django, docker, ubuntu, deployment

I have a Django project with written Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. Projects works as expected on localhost and I want to deploy it to already created ubuntu machine. I tried to manage that with Ansible but haven't succeeded. I use postgresql to store data
my docker file

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: Please [do not](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver) deploy with `manage.py runserver`! It is clearly stated in documentation and have been discussed on SO a few times. See [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/) for deployment checklist and instructions for multiple methods.